# Анализ SEO

Tags: seo, php

Существуют такие понятия как Web Mining и Data Mining, исходя из них задам вопрос - мы пропарсили весь сайт, получили список всех страниц, видим что есть узлы типа /news/.. или /catalog/.. и далее идут страницы, так вот как проанализировать(вывести) узлы отдельно, а все остальное в них отдельно, интересен сам алгоритм определения и вывода, спасибо.

Comment: Тут любопытно написано: [Web Mining: основные понятия](http://www.basegroup.ru/library/web_mining/basic_conceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, изобретаем велосипед, но интересно : )

У любого элемента есть родитель, и иногда он сам является родителем.
Узлы, в данном случае, имеют дочерние элементы, а страницы - нет.
Нужно разбить URL каждой страницы по слэшам, и вычислить единственного родителя:

```
$url1 = '/news/2012-08-31.html'; // родитель 'news'
$url2 = '/archive/news/2012/08/31/glavnaya_novost.html'; // родитель '31', но именно тот, у которого, в свою очередь, родитель '08', и не любой, а .. ну вы поняли) 
// Результат разбивки:
array('archive','news','2012','08','31','glavnaya_novost.html');
```

Завести массив $parents где будет запись про каждого уникального родителя, напр.

```
$parents[99] = array( 'url'=>'31', parentId=>19, childs=>0);
```

Тут хранится имя и указание на родителя. У корневого родитель Null. Теперь новый урл нужно пройти по элементам слева направо: от корня до конца, создавая родителей, если их ещё нет, и поднимая счётчик дочерних элементов, для очередного родителя.

Вывести узлы — все элементы, у которых `childs>0`, <br>вывести страницы — все, где `childs=0`.